# Appearance of Ruby's Mother

Tags: rwby

I just finished the latest volume of *RWBY*. I didn't get a clue about Ruby's Mom, but I'm still curious though.

Yang succeeds in finding her mother which is Raven Branwen and I'm already satisfied with the answer because Yang got her picture. But I'm dissatisfied with Ruby's mother which is in the white robe.

[image: from volume 3 chapter 4]

What about her weapon? Her semblance? Her appearance? Can we determine who Ruby's mother is from these?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I was asking about her mother identity

Comment: It seems "*a sixth volume is set to premiere on October 27, 2018*" (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RWBY)). So, considering the anime is still continuing, we might need to wait until that time, though I won't promise that your question will be answered on the next volume.

Comment: "What about her weapon? Her semblance? Her appearance?" - ...What about them? It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking what we know about her mother? If you're up to date on the series, I don't know what you expect anyone else to know that you don't already know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that Summer Rose is a Huntress in the same year and team as Qrow, Taiyang, Raven, and Summer. Each character seems to be similar to another character from TEAM RWBY. Summer seems to be very similar to Ruby at the time. She's shy, which is why she hides under her cloak, and also looks very similar to Ruby.

Identity-wise, all that is known is Summer is Ruby's birth mother, and Yang's stepmother. She died when they were young, and that's all the fans really know. Hopefully, Volume 6 gives us a little more depth.